# Drawing values from a multivariate normal distribution with an analytic covariance

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $C=[c_{i,j}]$ be a (very large) covariance matrix with the $c_{i,j}$-s having analytic expressions. $c_{i,j}=c_{j,i}$.

How would one draw values from the distribution without storing $C$ and without computing a Choleksy decomposition, which would require $O(n^2)$ storage? E.g., via repeated updates of the sampled vector $v$?

Eseentially I'd like to draw values "on-the-fly" without the storage cost, and ideally not exceeding the $O(n^3)$ computation cost.

Comment: When you write "analytic expression" do you mean "analytic" in the sense of complex analytic as in Cauchy-Riemann equations, complex residues, etc, or just that you have a formula or short computer code for computing particular values of  $c_{i,j}$ ?

Comment: Real analytic functions. What I want, is to draw a distribution on the fly.

Comment: Can you give some more context to this?  A covariance matrix has $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ independent parameters.  I don’t see how you can store less than this amount of information (unless you’re looking for a lower-dimensional approximation which doesn’t seem to be what you’re asking).

Comment: I have a set of functions $\{c_{i,j}\}$ that are the pair-wise covariances. Computationally those are analytic expressions, they don't need to be stored. Computing a decomposition however requires a large amount of storage. I wonder if there is another way? I probably won't save on computation requirements, which is fine, however I'd like to save on storage.

Comment: can you sample along one dimension, say $i_0$ and then use the covariance matrix entry at $[i_0,j_0]$ to draw sample along $j_0$ given your sampled $i$ value .. so if you are $z_i$ away from mean of $i$ then you would be $c_{jj}+c_{ij} z_i$ away from mean of $j$?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this with the covariance given, but if you are given the inverse covariance, you could try a markov Chain Monte Carlo to generate more samples with the correct  measure. It would be extremely time consuming, but at each point you only need to evaluate the matrix elements sequentually.